# How to select multiple row values coma separated in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get all the ids with coma separated while doing eloquent relationship.

So here is my current queries

```
Divrank::where('division_id', 591)->with('meta')->orderBy('position', 'asc')->get()
```

`Divrank` table has a one to many relation with `Divrankmeta` model. So with `meta` I am trying to return

```
public function meta(){
    return $this->hasOne(Divrankmeta::class)->selectRaw('id, match_id,divrank_id, sum(won) as won, sum(loss) as loss, sum(draw) as draw, sum(points) as points, sum(matchePlayed) as matchePlayed, sum(totalSets) as totalSets, sum(totalGames) totalGames')
    ->groupBy('divrank_id');
}
```

So far this query works fine..

I get the result like this screenshot

[image]

Ok so in my `Divrankmeta` model, I have a column called `winAgainst` and it can have some ids and some left null. So with the meta relation I want to retrieve `winAgainst` ids with coma separated string inside meta object.

For better understanding, here is how `Divrankmeta` table looks like

[image]

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: You didn't fetch `winAgainst` from `Divrankmeta`.

Answer (score 1):

The relation you created is one-to-one not one-to-many. That's why you are getting a meta object of the first matched row instead of an array that contains all related meta records.

I never put the modification codes into the eloquent functions. Those codes seem belongs to somewhere else. From my perspective, using "resources" and modifying the data there is a better idea.

If you chose the do so:

```
// Divrank.php
public function metas()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Divrankmeta');
}

// Divrankmeta.php
public function divrank()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Divrank');
}

// DivrankController
public function index()
{
  return DivrankResource::collection(Divrank::with("metas")->all());
}
```

Create a resource file.

```
php artisan make:resource DivrankResource
```

Now, you can modify your Divrank collection on the resource file before your controller returns it.

```
public function toArray($request)
{
   $metaIds = [];
   forEach($this->metas as $meta) {
     array_push($metaIds, $meta['id']);
   }
   $this['metaIds'] = $metaIds;
   return parent::toArray($request);
}
```

I'm not able to test this code. But it will probably work. If you don't want to use resources, you can create the same functionality in your controller as well. Bu we like to make controllers as short as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it works my answer.. It has one to many relations but I need one data object so one to one relations is placed with a group by so it returns one record only. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I solved it, These are the changes I did. Thanks

```
return $this->hasOne(Divrankmeta::class)
    // ->selectRaw('id, match_id,divrank_id, sum(won) as won, sum(loss) as loss, sum(draw) as draw, sum(points) as points, sum(matchePlayed) as matchePlayed,
    // sum(totalSets) as totalSets, sum(totalGames) totalGames')
    ->select(\DB::raw("id, match_id,divrank_id, sum(won) as won, sum(loss) as loss, sum(draw) as draw, sum(points) as points, sum(matchePlayed) as matchePlayed,
    sum(totalSets) as totalSets, sum(totalGames) totalGames, GROUP_CONCAT(winAgainst) as winAgainst"))->groupBy('divrank_id');
```